# Mongoose find does not return results mongo does

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a method called getTeamEmployees which should get employees that have teamId equals to the method parameter teamId. It looks like this:

```
public getTeamEmployees(teamId: number): Promise<any> {
    return MDBDatabaseController.EmployeeModel.find({ teamId: teamId }).exec();
}
```

I have enabled mongoose debug and in the console I can see what query mongoose execute. This is the query:

```
employees.find({ teamId: 13 }, { fields: {} })
```

If I execute this using the mongo shell I get this:

```
    db.employees.find({ teamId: 13 }, { fields: {} })
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : ">1 field in obj: {}",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

And if I execute it without the { fields: {} } part everything is ok. It gives me 5 results.

I'm using mongoose with typescript and my model is instantiated like this:

```
MDBDatabaseController.EmployeeModel = model<IEmployee>('Employee', EmployeeSchema.schema);
```

Where **IEmployee** is an interface that extends **mongoose.Document** and has a field called **teamId** that is of type **Number** capital N.

**EmployeeSchema** is a class that has a static property called 'schema' that is equal to a new instance of **mongoose.Schema** which has a property called **teamId** of type **Number**.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Looks like somehow the find method is adding { fields: {} } in the find query. Worth checking the mongoose version you are using. Also try doing it with a simple model class instead of static property. Then you will come to know about the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was doing something wrong in the resolve function of the promise. I was doing something like 
`res.status(200).send({})`
. So no matter what query was executed all that I was getting back on the client side was {}.